# Bug or Feature? Grep accepts files as flags

Tags: grep, wildcards, options

I just ran into a weird scenario, and I'm not sure if this is a feature, and if not, what sort of security implications does it represent? Likely nothing for grep, but other directory-crawling utilities, potentially?

Here's how to reproduce:

- `touch ./-vR`
- `grep hi *`

Notice that everything not `hi` is returned, recursively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a known misfeature of GNU `getopt` (used for option parsing by GNU tools).

```
grep hi -vR
```

is required by POSIX to look for `hi` in the file called `-vR` as options many not be recognised past non-option arguments (like `hi` here).

Most GNU tools or tools making use or the GNU `getopt` API in the default mode don't honour that unless `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment.

So you need either:

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 grep hi *
```

(force `grep` to behave in a POSIX compliant way) or

```
grep -- hi *
```

(explicitly mark the end of options with `--`) or

```
grep hi ./*
```

(make sure all file names start with `./`, and so not `-`).

In any case, with:

```
grep -e hi -vR
```

you'd have the problem with GNU and non-GNU `grep` as that `hi` is not a non-option argument, but an argument to the `-e` option, so you'd need:

```
grep -e hi -- *
```

or (better as it also addresses the problem of a file called `-`):

```
grep -e hi ./*
```

(POSIXLY_CORRECT wouldn't help).

Answer (score 4):

This is a "feature" of GNU `grep` (and other GNU utilities that does the command line parsing in the same way).  The command line parsing routines that GNU uses allows for flags to be specified *after* what's supposed to be the final operand on the command line.

To work around this, explicitly tell the utility that there will be no more command line flags:

```
$ grep -- hi *
```

This forces `grep` to treat the filenames expanded from `*` by the shell as filenames and not as options.